# rails ancestry association collection sort order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I have a Locations table that uses the Ancestry gem.  I would like to sort the entries when I'm using the "subtree" selection.

This works without subtree:

```
<%= f.association :location, :label_method => :name_desc, :collection => Location.all(:order => :name) %>
```

But, this doesn't work:

```
<%= f.association :location, :label_method => :name_desc, :collection => Location.find(locationid).subtree(:order => :name) %>
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown depth option: order.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Define "doesn't work"... Do you get an error, or is it simply not ordered?

Comment: I don’t think the subtree is supposed to be used like that. Documentation of Ancestry atleast says something totally different.